# Debian 9 SendMail Issues with DSN

Tags: php, debian, sendmail

i am currently losing my mind by working on a issue found on my server today, i searched a lot at google about this issue but could not find the right way to fix my issue.

This is the current state:
I bought a rootserver a few days ago, i installed apache2, mysql and php on the server. The server holds a simple website were you can register your account. To register your account you will need to confirm you email address, the issue is that not all my friends receive an email. I used a gmail account to receive emails and it worked for it, i tested it on a trashmail and it worked aswell. My friends use gmx.net to receive emails, but my server can't send mails to them. The server is pretty new and i only installed the LAMP Package to run my website.

This is what i found in the logs:
The logs tell me that the DSN of gmx.net can't be reached, the logfile looks like that:

```
Apr 19 02:23:33 h2880388 sendmail[22059]: 03J0NXWV022059: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 02:23:33 h2880388 sendmail[22059]: 03J0NXWV022059: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233559, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190023.03J0NXWV022059@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 02:23:33 h2880388 sm-mta[22062]: 03J0NXKr022062: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233918, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190023.03J0NXWV022059@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 02:23:34 h2880388 sendmail[22059]: 03J0NXWV022059: to=MYFRIEND2@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=263559, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J0NXKr022062 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 02:23:34 h2880388 sm-mta[22064]: 03J0NXKr022062: to=<MYFRIEND2@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353918, relay=mx00.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.15.9], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:23:34 h2880388 sm-mta[22064]: 03J0NXKr022062: 03J0NYKr022064: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:23:34 h2880388 sm-mta[22064]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:26:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22095]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:02:30, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:26:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22095]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=02:26:58, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1380000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:36:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22202]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:12:30, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:36:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22202]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=02:36:58, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1470000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:44:01 h2880388 sendmail[22356]: 03J0i1T9022356: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 02:44:01 h2880388 sendmail[22356]: 03J0i1T9022356: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233559, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190044.03J0i1T9022356@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 02:44:01 h2880388 sm-mta[22357]: 03J0i1m9022357: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233918, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190044.03J0i1T9022356@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 02:44:01 h2880388 sendmail[22356]: 03J0i1T9022356: to=MYFRIEND2@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=263559, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J0i1m9022357 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 02:44:01 h2880388 sm-mta[22359]: 03J0i1m9022357: to=<MYFRIEND2@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353918, relay=mx01.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.17.5], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:44:01 h2880388 sm-mta[22359]: 03J0i1m9022357: 03J0i1m9022359: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:44:01 h2880388 sm-mta[22359]: 03J0i1m9022359: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:46:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22376]: 03J0i1m9022359: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:02:03, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:46:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22376]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:22:30, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=300000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:46:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22376]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=02:46:58, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1560000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:55:36 h2880388 sendmail[22460]: 03J0taq2022460: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 02:55:37 h2880388 sendmail[22460]: 03J0taq2022460: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233559, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190055.03J0taq2022460@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 02:55:37 h2880388 sm-mta[22461]: 03J0tbmc022461: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233918, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190055.03J0taq2022460@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 02:55:37 h2880388 sendmail[22460]: 03J0taq2022460: to=MYFRIEND2@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=263559, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J0tbmc022461 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 02:55:37 h2880388 sm-mta[22463]: 03J0tbmc022461: to=<MYFRIEND2@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353918, relay=mx00.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.15.9], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:55:37 h2880388 sm-mta[22463]: 03J0tbmc022461: 03J0tbmc022463: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:55:37 h2880388 sm-mta[22463]: 03J0tbmc022463: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:56:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22466]: 03J0tbmc022463: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:27, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:56:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22466]: 03J0i1m9022359: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:12:03, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:56:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22466]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:32:30, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=390000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:56:04 h2880388 sm-mta[22466]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=02:56:58, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1650000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:58:52 h2880388 sm-mta[22589]: starting daemon (8.15.2): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Apr 19 02:58:52 h2880388 sm-mta[22590]: 03J0tbmc022463: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:03:15, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:58:52 h2880388 sm-mta[22590]: 03J0i1m9022359: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:14:51, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=300000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:58:52 h2880388 sm-mta[22590]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:35:18, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=480000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:58:52 h2880388 sm-mta[22590]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=02:59:46, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1740000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:59:00 h2880388 sendmail[22603]: 03J0x0D3022603: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 02:59:00 h2880388 sendmail[22603]: 03J0x0D3022603: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233567, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190059.03J0x0D3022603@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 02:59:00 h2880388 sm-mta[22604]: 03J0x0R8022604: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233926, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190059.03J0x0D3022603@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 02:59:01 h2880388 sendmail[22603]: 03J0x0D3022603: to=marek.salzinger@gmail.com, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=263567, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J0x0R8022604 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 02:59:01 h2880388 sm-mta[22606]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.3, verify=FAIL, cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits=256/256
Apr 19 02:59:02 h2880388 sm-mta[22606]: 03J0x0R8022604: to=<marek.salzinger@gmail.com>, delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=353926, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [173.194.79.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK  1587257942 f4si16508407ejf.337 - gsmtp)
Apr 19 02:59:13 h2880388 sendmail[22608]: 03J0xDHv022608: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 02:59:13 h2880388 sendmail[22608]: 03J0xDHv022608: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233560, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190059.03J0xDHv022608@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 02:59:13 h2880388 sm-mta[22609]: 03J0xDFh022609: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233919, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190059.03J0xDHv022608@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 02:59:13 h2880388 sendmail[22608]: 03J0xDHv022608: to=MYFRIEND1@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=263560, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J0xDFh022609 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 02:59:13 h2880388 sm-mta[22611]: 03J0xDFh022609: to=<MYFRIEND1@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353919, relay=mx00.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.15.9], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:59:13 h2880388 sm-mta[22611]: 03J0xDFh022609: 03J0xDFh022611: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:59:14 h2880388 sm-mta[22611]: 03J0xDFh022611: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 02:59:44 h2880388 sendmail[22626]: 03J0xiBa022626: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 02:59:44 h2880388 sendmail[22626]: 03J0xiBa022626: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233559, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190059.03J0xiBa022626@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 02:59:44 h2880388 sm-mta[22627]: 03J0xiMp022627: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233918, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190059.03J0xiBa022626@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 02:59:44 h2880388 sendmail[22626]: 03J0xiBa022626: to=MYFRIEND2@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=263559, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J0xiMp022627 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 02:59:44 h2880388 sm-mta[22629]: 03J0xiMp022627: to=<MYFRIEND2@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353918, relay=mx01.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.17.5], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:59:44 h2880388 sm-mta[22629]: 03J0xiMp022627: 03J0xiMp022629: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 02:59:44 h2880388 sm-mta[22629]: 03J0xiMp022629: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:06:59 h2880388 sendmail[22697]: 03J16xVu022697: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 03:06:59 h2880388 sendmail[22697]: 03J16xVu022697: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233560, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190106.03J16xVu022697@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 03:06:59 h2880388 sm-mta[22698]: 03J16x2k022698: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233919, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190106.03J16xVu022697@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 03:07:00 h2880388 sendmail[22697]: 03J16xVu022697: to=MYFRIEND1@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=263560, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J16x2k022698 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 03:07:00 h2880388 sm-mta[22700]: 03J16x2k022698: to=<MYFRIEND1@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353919, relay=mx01.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.17.5], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:07:00 h2880388 sm-mta[22700]: 03J16x2k022698: 03J1702k022700: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:07:00 h2880388 sm-mta[22700]: 03J1702k022700: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22802]: starting daemon (8.15.2): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22803]: 03J1702k022700: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:01:10, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22803]: 03J0xDFh022611: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:08:57, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22803]: 03J0xiMp022629: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:08:26, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22803]: 03J0tbmc022463: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:12:33, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=300000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22803]: 03J0i1m9022359: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:24:09, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=390000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22803]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:44:36, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=570000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:10 h2880388 sm-mta[22803]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=03:09:04, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1830000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:08:16 h2880388 sendmail[22817]: 03J18GG0022817: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 03:08:16 h2880388 sendmail[22817]: 03J18GG0022817: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233559, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190108.03J18GG0022817@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 03:08:17 h2880388 sm-mta[22818]: 03J18HDr022818: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233918, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190108.03J18GG0022817@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 03:08:17 h2880388 sendmail[22817]: 03J18GG0022817: to=MYFRIEND2@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=263559, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J18HDr022818 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 03:08:17 h2880388 sm-mta[22820]: 03J18HDr022818: to=<MYFRIEND2@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353918, relay=mx00.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.15.9], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:08:17 h2880388 sm-mta[22820]: 03J18HDr022818: 03J18HDr022820: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:08:17 h2880388 sm-mta[22820]: 03J18HDr022820: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:50 h2880388 sendmail[23498]: alias database /etc/mail/aliases rebuilt by root
Apr 19 03:16:50 h2880388 sendmail[23498]: /etc/mail/aliases: 12 aliases, longest 10 bytes, 134 bytes total
Apr 19 03:16:54 h2880388 sm-mta[22802]: restarting /usr/sbin/sendmail-mta due to signal
Apr 19 03:16:54 h2880388 sm-mta[23554]: starting daemon (8.15.2): SMTP+queueing@00:10:00
Apr 19 03:16:54 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03J18HDr022820: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:08:37, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:54 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03J1702k022700: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:09:54, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03J0xDFh022611: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:17:42, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03J0xiMp022629: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:17:11, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03J0tbmc022463: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:21:18, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=390000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03J0i1m9022359: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:32:54, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=480000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:53:21, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=660000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:16:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23555]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=03:17:49, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=1920000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:17:14 h2880388 sendmail[23572]: 03J1HEex023572: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 03:17:14 h2880388 sendmail[23572]: 03J1HEex023572: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233559, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190117.03J1HEex023572@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 03:17:14 h2880388 sm-mta[23573]: 03J1HECv023573: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233918, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190117.03J1HEex023572@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 03:17:15 h2880388 sendmail[23572]: 03J1HEex023572: to=MYFRIEND2@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=263559, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J1HECv023573 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 03:17:15 h2880388 sm-mta[23575]: 03J1HECv023573: to=<MYFRIEND2@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=353918, relay=mx01.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.17.5], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:17:15 h2880388 sm-mta[23575]: 03J1HECv023573: 03J1HFCv023575: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:17:15 h2880388 sm-mta[23575]: 03J1HFCv023575: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:17:55 h2880388 sendmail[23580]: 03J1HtsT023580: Authentication-Warning: h2880388.stratoserver.net: www-data set sender to noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de using -f
Apr 19 03:17:55 h2880388 sendmail[23580]: 03J1HtsT023580: from=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de, size=233560, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190117.03J1HtsT023580@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, relay=www-data@localhost
Apr 19 03:17:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23581]: 03J1HtRJ023581: from=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, size=233919, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202004190117.03J1HtsT023580@h2880388.stratoserver.net>, bodytype=8BITMIME, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Apr 19 03:17:55 h2880388 sendmail[23580]: 03J1HtsT023580: to=MYFRIEND1@gmx.de, ctladdr=noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=263560, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (03J1HtRJ023581 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr 19 03:17:56 h2880388 sm-mta[23583]: 03J1HtRJ023581: to=<MYFRIEND1@gmx.de>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=353919, relay=mx01.emig.gmx.net. [212.227.17.5], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:17:56 h2880388 sm-mta[23583]: 03J1HtRJ023581: 03J1HuRJ023583: DSN: Service unavailable
Apr 19 03:17:56 h2880388 sm-mta[23583]: 03J1HuRJ023583: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:54 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J1HFCv023575: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:09:39, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de. [85.214.126.92], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J1HuRJ023583: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:08:59, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J18HDr022820: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:18:38, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=210000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J1702k022700: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:19:55, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=300000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J0xDFh022611: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:27:42, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=300000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J0xiMp022629: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:27:11, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=300000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J0tbmc022463: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:31:18, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=480000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J0i1m9022359: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=00:42:54, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=570000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03J0NYKr022064: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=01:03:21, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=750000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
Apr 19 03:26:55 h2880388 sm-mta[23688]: 03ILx6xU018770: to=<noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de>, delay=03:27:49, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=2010000, relay=MYWEBSITEURL.de., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by MYWEBSITEURL.de.
```

i didn't setup any service to receive emails yet.
i send the Email with a PHP script that looks like that

```
// Recipient 
  $to = $reciever; 

  // Sender 
  $from = 'noreply@MYWEBSITEURL.de'; 
  $fromName = 'MYWEBSITENAME'; 

  // Email subject 
  $subject = 'Bestätigen sie ihren Account auf MYWEBSITENAME';  

  // Attachment file 
  $file = "./MY_ATTACHMENT.pdf"; 

  // Email body content 
  $htmlContent = '
  SOME FANCY HTML CODE THAT I DONT WANT TO POST HERE
  '; 

  // Header for sender info 
  $headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">"; 

  // Boundary  
  $semi_rand = md5(time());  
  $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  

  // Headers for attachment  
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

  // Multipart boundary  
  $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" . 
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";  

  // Preparing attachment 
  if(!empty($file) > 0){ 
    if(is_file($file)){ 
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
      $fp =    @fopen($file,"rb"); 
      $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($file)); 

      @fclose($fp); 
      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
      $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($file)."\"\n" .  
      "Content-Description: ".basename($file)."\n" . 
      "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($file)."\"; size=".filesize($file).";\n" .  
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n"; 
    } 
  } 
  $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--"; 
  $returnpath = "-f" . $from; 

  // Send email 
  $mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);  

  // Email sending status 
  echo $mail?"send":"send_error";
```

This worked fine for gmail.com but not for gmx.net or web.de

my telnet connection response is

```
Trying 85.214.126.92...
Connected to 85.214.126.92.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 schnellverliebt.de ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-8; Sun, 19 Apr 2020 19:28:05 +0200; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: MYWEBSITEURL.de(OK)-MYWEBSITEURL.de [85.214.126.92]
```

I hope you can help me to get arround this issue, thanks for your time.

Comment: The logs show that your servers tries to contact 85.214.126.92:25 but it is unable to establish SMTP connection.  Do you get SMTP greeting when you execute `telnet 85.214.126.92 25` on the host?  NO => it is not sendmail's fault.

Comment: no i don't, my telnet conntection prints the following: Trying 85.214.126.92...
Connected to 85.214.126.92.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 schnellverliebt.de ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-8; Sun, 19 Apr 2020 12:19:10 +0200; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: schnellverliebt.de(OK)-schnellverliebt.de [85.214.126.92]

Comment: Do you use persistent host status? What is reported by `sendmail -bh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this issue by adding a reverse DNS entry to my domain to resolve the IP to my Domain that is sending the email. This fixed the issue for me and now all emails are delivered :)